# Can't catch "Prelude.read: no parse" exception with Control.Exception.try

Tags: haskell

I trying to read some value out of a file and catch every exception that might occur (in the mindset of ["Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission"](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp)). I am having trouble catching the `Prelude.read: no parse` exception though. To tell `try` that it should catch every exception I define `tryAny` with the explicit type `SomeException` which to my knowledge is the "super type" of every exception:

```
import Control.Exception (try,SomeException)
tryAny :: IO a -> IO (Either SomeException a)
tryAny = try
```

With `tryAny` I seem to be able to catch IO errors:

```
> tryAny (fromFile "nonExistingFileName")
Left nonExistingFileName: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

But the read error will not be caught:

```
> tryAny (return ((read "a")::Int))
Right *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

What can I do to catch every exception?

Comment: If you are trying to solve that particular problem, you might want to give the *safe* package a try. The [Safe module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-0.3.3/docs/Safe.html) exports, among other things, `readMay` which returns the read value as a `Maybe` value.

Comment: @kqr Thanks, that's a good suggestion. I'll use that for my next `read`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` does not evaluate its argument, and thus doesn't throw any exceptions. The evaluation happens outside of `tryAny`, when you try to print the result.

Use `evaluate` (possibly together with `force` from `Control.DeepSeq`, depending on your real situation) for that.

Comment: Rather than `evaluate`, it might be simpler to use a parsing library that models failure explicitly.  I.e. anything other than `read`.

Comment: There's `readMaybe` in the recent versions of `base`. But this question seems to be about exceptions, not parsing.

Comment: True, that's why I upvoted your answer.  But `read` is probably not the right tool for the job either.

Comment: @JohnL It probably isn't. I chose `read` because it looked pleasingly  simple, but error handling, especially with lazy IO, is sooo annoying.

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka: Where can I find documentation for `readMaybe` and how recent does my GHC have do be? I have 7.6.2 and could neither find it in ghci nor online on Hackage. Also, thanks for your answer :). I was now able to find a solution using `evaluate` and `force` (see below).

Comment: @Perseids If you don't have `readMaybe` you can use the older `reads` which is slighly more cumbersome.

Comment: @Perseids It's present since GHC 7.6.1 (base 4.6) in the `Text.Read` module: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe

Comment: RomanCheplyaka: Great, thx :D. @Ørjan Johansen: Oh, I've seen that before parsing hex encodes integers. It's a little bit too mighty and thus complex for my use cases :).

Answer (score 2):

After a *lot* of experimenting with `evaluate`, `force` and `try`, following the suggestions of @Roman Cheplyaka, I've come up with this solution, which seems almost blazingly obvious now I see the final result:

```
import Control.DeepSeq (force,NFData)
import Control.Exception (try,SomeException)

tryAnyStrict :: NFData a => IO a -> IO (Either SomeException a)
tryAnyStrict = try.evaluateIoCompletely

evaluateIoCompletely :: NFData a => IO a -> IO a
evaluateIoCompletely ioA = do
    a <- ioA
    evaluate $ force a
```

This solution splits the process up into a function that will enforce strict evaluation and throw all exceptions and a wrapper that will catch these exceptions. `force` returns a pure haskell object that itself has to be evaluated first to force deep evaluation of `a`. From the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.3.0.1/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html):

> ```
> force x = x `deepseq` x
> ```
>
> force x fully evaluates x, and then returns it. Note that force x only performs evaluation when the value of force x itself is demanded, so essentially it turns shallow evaluation into deep evaluation.

There are a few subtle points of this implementation that went wrong in my earlier tries:

- If you use `ioA` directly as input to `force` instead of `a` then you will end up with an object of type `IO (IO a)`, as `evaluate` has type `b -> IO b`. This immediate problem can be solved with some unwrap function of type `IO(IO a) -> IO a`, but then you will get a problem with the typeclass assumption of `NFData a`, which now needs to be `NFData (IO a)`. But for `IO a` there seems to be no instance declarations available, at least for `a::(String,String)`.
- Instead of using two functions you could just use `tryAnyStrict = do a <- ioA; (try.evaluate.force) a`. The problem then is that exceptions arising from `a <- ioA` will not be caught, for example if `ioA` is the result of `serialized <- readFile; return $ read serialized` and the file that is to be read from does not exist.
- You cannot inline `try.evaluateIoCompletely` in your code without type information, because try needs to know which exception it is supposed to catch. This information is now supplied via the return type of `tryAnyStrict` which resolves the type `e` of `try :: Exception e => IO a -> IO (Either e a)` to the most general exception type `SomeException`.

Now after I got `tryAnyStrict` working I still have problems with lazy evaluation, because if `a <- ioA` fails - where ioA is the result of `read` on a string read lazily from a file - (for example the file content does not have the format necessary for `read`) then the file is still not completely read and thus still opened. A subsequent write on the file will fail ("openFile: resource busy"). So... I might actually rewrite the whole code yet again using `readMay` or `readMaybe` as suggested by @kqr and @Roman Cheplyaka and also force a strict read of the file directly.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and didn't find `readMaybe` as suggested in some of the comments. But I found another useful read variation which solved my problem - [readIO](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readIO)

> The readIO function is similar to read except that it signals parse failure to the IO monad instead of terminating the program.

Using it I was able to catch and process all errors in my program.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use [safe-exceptions](https://www.stackage.org/package/safe-exceptions)

You can `import Control.Exception.Safe` and use [tryAnyDeep](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.4/safe-exceptions-0.1.6.0/Control-Exception-Safe.html#v:tryAnyDeep)

```
tryDeep :: (C.MonadCatch m, MonadIO m, E.Exception e, NFData a) => m a -> m (Either e a)
tryDeep f = catch (liftM Right (evaluateDeep f)) (return . Left)
tryAnyDeep :: (C.MonadCatch m, MonadIO m, NFData a) => m a -> m (Either SomeException a)
tryAnyDeep = tryDeep
```

But it solution expect a has `deriving (NFData)`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17302818)

Comment: I append description.